# $\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}$ meaning?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, terminology

What is this called and what does it mean?

$\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}$
does it mean you differentiate an expression with respect to $t$, $n$ times?

Is there a name for this? I want to do some research

Comment: It is the $n^{th}$ derivative that is to say the result after $n$ derivations. No name as far as I know.

Comment: It is called a "differential operator". It is a function that takes functions as inputs and outputs derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice, the nth derivative of a function with respect to $t$:
>
> - $$\frac{\text{d}^1f(t)}{\text{d}t^1}=f^{(1)}(t)=f'(t)$$
> - $$\frac{\text{d}^2f(t)}{\text{d}t^2}=f^{(2)}(t)=f''(t)$$
> - $$\frac{\text{d}^3f(t)}{\text{d}t^3}=f^{(3)}(t)=f'''(t)$$
> - $$\frac{\text{d}^4f(t)}{\text{d}t^4}=f^{(4)}(t)=f''''(t)$$

So:

$$\frac{\text{d}^nf(t)}{\text{d}t^n}=f^{(n)}(t)$$